# Split row into multiple rows while evenly distribute certain values and keep certain static

Tags: python, algorithm, split

I have a table in a JSON format (list of dicts), where each row is a dict.

Say for simplicity that I have a row like this:

```
{
    'dimension1': 'foo',
    'dimension2': 'bar',
    'metric1': 102,
    'metric2': 200
}
```

I would like to know if there a simple way (maybe using pandas or any other python tool), to split this row into a given number of `n` rows where:

1. Dimensions will be kept as is.
2. Metrics values will be splitted evenly across all rows.
3. All metrics are `int` and should be kept `int`.
4. The sum should be equal to the original row.

For example, if `n = 4`, the output for the row above should be:

```
[{
    'dimension1': 'foo',
    'dimension2': 'bar',
    'metric1': 25,
    'metric2': 50
},{
    'dimension1': 'foo',
    'dimension2': 'bar',
    'metric1': 25,
    'metric2': 50
},{
    'dimension1': 'foo',
    'dimension2': 'bar',
    'metric1': 26,
    'metric2': 50
},{
    'dimension1': 'foo',
    'dimension2': 'bar',
    'metric1': 26,
    'metric2': 50
}]
```

I tried to search for a way of doing this with `pandas` or other tools, but couldn't find a way to give a set of dimensions that should be kept static and a set of metrics that should be splitted while keeping the sum.

Hope this is clear enough. I know it's possible to write this logic explicitly but wanted to know if there's any simpler, more robust way I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be the cleanest one but give it a go using `np.histrogram` to convert the values into bins

```
def value_to_bins(df_value,n):
    value=np.arange(df_value, dtype=int)
    return np.histogram(value, bins=n)[0]

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d={
    'dimension1': 'foo',
    'dimension2': 'bar',
    'metric1': 101,
    'metric2': 200
}
df=pd.DataFrame(d,index=[0])
n=2

df2=pd.DataFrame(index=range(n),columns=['dimension1','dimension2']) # create new dataframe with NaN
df2.dimension1=df2.dimension1.fillna(df.dimension1[0]) # fill with values of previous dimension1
df2.dimension2=df2.dimension2.fillna(df.dimension2[0]) # fill with values of previous dimension2

df2['metric1'] = value_to_bins(df.metric1[0],n)
df2['metric2'] = value_to_bins(df.metric2[0],n)
df2.to_dict('records')
```

**Output**

```
[{'dimension1': 'foo', 'dimension2': 'bar', 'metric1': 50L, 'metric2': 100L},
 {'dimension1': 'foo', 'dimension2': 'bar', 'metric1': 51L, 'metric2': 100L}]
```

To keep the `int` values

```
[{k:int(v) if v!=np.nan and k in ['metric1','metric2']  else v for k,v in i.items() } for i in df2.to_dict('records')]
```

**Output**

```
[{'dimension1': 'foo', 'dimension2': 'bar', 'metric1': 50, 'metric2': 100},
 {'dimension1': 'foo', 'dimension2': 'bar', 'metric1': 51, 'metric2': 100}]
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I agree that it's doesn't look so clean but it's the cleaner than what I could think of. I have taken your idea and made it a bit more generic. Would be nicer to loop over the dimensions and metrics instead of explicitly writing them down. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use floor and list comprehension and dictionary comprehension :
idea is calculation floor then divide and share reminder by 1 for each element to have close element as much as possible, for example assuming `102` and  `n=4` we have `reminder=2`, so result is : `25+1,25+1,25,25`

```
import math

data={
'dimension1': 'foo',
'dimension2': 'bar',
'metric1': 102,
'metric2': 203
}
#finds all keys with integer values
division_fields=[k for k,v in data.items() if str(v).isdigit()]
values={}
n=4
#creates a list with desired  values for each numeric field
#and diveds reminder betweens elements of list by 1 foreach element 
for  field in division_fields:
    values[field]= [math.floor(data[field]/n) if i+1>data[field]%n else math.floor(data[field]/n)+1 for i in range(0,n)]

result=[{k:values[k][i] if k in division_fields else v for k,v in data.items() } for i in range(0,n)]

print (result)
```

Output(for n=4):

```
[{'dimension1': 'foo', 'dimension2': 'bar', 'metric1': 26, 'metric2': 51},
 {'dimension1': 'foo', 'dimension2': 'bar', 'metric1': 26, 'metric2': 51},
 {'dimension1': 'foo', 'dimension2': 'bar', 'metric1': 25, 'metric2': 51},
 {'dimension1': 'foo', 'dimension2': 'bar', 'metric1': 25, 'metric2': 50}]
```

Comment: The value for metric2 should not remain as 200 it should be 50 as per the value you opted

Comment: @MehrdadDowlatabadi What will happen if `metric1` is `102`? If I understand your solution correctly, the last element will have now 27. I want it to be evenly (as much as possible), meaning that two rows will be 26 and two 25.
I'll also update my question accordingly.